# Display functions without dependence?

Tags: functions, output, display

I'm solving systems of equations with a few different functions of time, t, and so I'm getting output with lots of [t] running around. Is there a way to display these functions without the dependences, e.g., to display

```
a[t] b'[t]
```

as

```
a b'
```

? I can use a series of replacement rules to do this, e.g.,

```
/.{a[t]->a,b[t]->b}
```

but this is pretty cumbersome, and doesn't generalize well (e.g., when more functions are added in).

Comment: Something like `a[t] b'[t] /. f_[t] :> f`? Please note that this could fail, depending on your expression.

Comment: Hi Yves, that works, thanks! Why do you use the delayed :> instead of ->?

Comment: Right, `Rule` (`->` ) works just as well in your case :)

Comment: @Yves With respect, no, it does not.  You *should* use `:>` with named patterns on the right-hand-side.  Otherwise if `f` has a global value the replacement will break.

Comment: This rule does not work for all functions of the independent variable. For example `a[t] Exp[t]` gives  `a Exp[t]`. But may be that is ok with the OP, just wanted to point it out just in case.

Comment: @Nasser it will only work for single-arguments while `Exp` uses two.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard thanks for pointing out the failure mode for already defined `f`.